# Getting trending topics from Twitter using tweepy. Is there a better way of doing it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

```
#import time
import tweepy
#import csv
import keys

#WOEID 455825
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("", "")
auth.set_access_token("",
                      "")


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys.consumer_key,
                           keys.consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(keys.access_token,


                      keys.access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True,
                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True)


trends_available = api.trends_available()

print(f"Number of Trends availables: {len(trends_available)}")
print()
rj_trends = api.trends_place(id =23424768 )
#23424768 Brasil
#print(f"RJ trending topics: \n{rj_trends}")
for trend in rj_trends:
    for i in trend.values():
        for x in i:
            if x["tweet_volume"] is not None:
                if  x["tweet_volume"] > 10000:
                     print(x["name"], x["tweet_volume"])
```

Example of output:

```
#PINKChella1Year 49997
#ConcertForBTS 108750
```

I have used a lot of nested for and nested if.Is there a clever way to get trending topics?
The code is working but I do not know I got an error :

```
 if x["tweet_volume"] is not None:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `rj_trends` is a list containing a dictionary containing a list.

So you can do this:

```
trends = []
for trend in rj_trends[0]['trends']: 
    if trend['tweet_volume'] is not None and trend['tweet_volume'] > 10000: 
        trends.append((trend['name'], trend['tweet_volume']))

trends.sort(key=lambda x:-x[1])
```

Result:

```
[('America', 816921),
 ('Felipe Neto', 117287),
 ('Maxon', 95250),
 ('Início', 88489),
 ('#LiveGabiMartinsEmCasa', 75254),
 ('#OneDirectionSave2020', 65309),
 ('Djonga', 64076),
 ('#PINKChella1year', 60945),
 ('TRÊS MILHÕES GIZELLYBICALHO', 42252),
 ('Roger', 41209),
 ('LUCASVIANA TE AMAMOS', 36672),
 ('Renan', 24669),
 ('Leal', 22745),
 ('IMUNIDADE PRA FLAY', 19824),
 ('ImaginaSamba', 18487),
 ('#BaileDoRennanDaPenhaEmCasa', 18059),
 ('#DennisNaFlaTV', 15938),
 ('Froy', 12630)]
```

Comment: How can I sort the result by "tweet_volume" ?

Comment: @LaurindaSouza: let me edit the answer with an example of that.

Comment: I did not understand the lambda!    trends.sort(key=lambda x:-x[1]

Comment: There's a 2-tuple and it's looking at the 2nd, or [1]th element in that tuple. Then since you probably want the most-tweeted-about trend we reverse the order with `-`.

Comment: Is it possible use itemgetter() from operator? Do you know how to use it?

Comment: How to get the topics of the trend? i.e Political, Entertainment, Sports etc. Twitter shows topics above some trend name.  I cannot post Question